# Homebrew: how to list installed bottles and their OS version?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I recently upgraded Mac OS X to Yosemite and I'd like to make sure that each package I have currently installed is a Yosemite bottle.

How can I list installed bottles and their OS version, so to eventually uninstall/install them?

---

**EDIT** Grepping the string "bottled" won't work because it is there anyway if a bottle is available for the package, but you can still compile from source. For example I've just built yasm from source and `brew info yasm` returns:

```
yasm: stable 1.3.0 (bottled), HEAD
Modular BSD reimplementation of NASM
http://yasm.tortall.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/yasm/1.3.0 (44 files, 3.3M) *
  Built from source
[...]
```

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to list all bottled formulae is to [query](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Querying-Brew.md) the JSON output of `brew info --json` directly (this requires `jq`):

```bash
brew info --json=v1 --installed | jq -r "map(select(.installed[].poured_from_bottle) | .name) | unique | .[]"
```

Here, `brew info --json=v1 --installed` provides the JSON-formatted info for all installed formulae. `jq` processes this (use it without arguments for a beautified output). `select(.installed[].poured_from_bottle)` picks every formula where there's at least one bottled version installed, and `map(... | .name)` returns the associated names. `| unique` ensures that, in the case where there are multiple bottled versions installed, the formula name is returned only once, `| .[]` breaks the returned array of names into a list, each on a separate line, and `-r` strips the quotes from the JSON output, leaving a format that can be passed into other shell commands.

That's a bit complicated to remember every time, but you can put this command into a shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#:  * `bottled` [<options>]:
#:
#:  List all bottled formulae which are currently installed.
#:
#:          --versions                   Show the version number for bottled 
#:                                       formulae
#:      -h, --help                       Show this message.
#:
#:  (`brew bottled` requires `jq`. Use `brew install jq` to install.)

if type jq &>/dev/null; then
  case $1 in
    --versions)
      brew info --json=v1 --installed | \
        jq -r "map(select(.installed[].poured_from_bottle) | .name + \" \" + .installed[].version) | .[]"
      ;;
    *)
      brew info --json=v1 --installed | \
        jq -r "map(select(.installed[].poured_from_bottle) | .name) | unique | .[]"
      ;;
  esac
  exit $?
else
  echo '`brew bottled` requires jq. Use `brew install jq` to install.'
  exit 1
fi
```

Call it `brew-bottled`, make it executable (`chmod a+x brew-bottled`) and place it somewhere in your path (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`). Now you can call it as an [external command](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/External-Commands.md) with `brew bottled` to list your bottled formulae. (As an added bonus, the `--versions` switch will include version information, similar to `brew list --versions`, including multiple bottled versions of the same formula.)

So, if you wanted to, say, rebuild all bottled formulae from source, you could then pipe this to through `xargs`:

```bash
brew-bottled | xargs brew reinstall -s
```

(Leave off the `-s` to simply reinstall the current OS bottles.)

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to determine what macOS version's bottle is currently installed, so you'd be looking at reinstalling all bottled formulae to be sure.

Comment: @James Bucanek,  I know when I updated to Big Sur. If I could find all the bottles that were poured before that date I would know they should be updated. How can I modify this formula to filter by date?

Comment: @Chris, John has a question...

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

There seems to be an `INSTALL_RECEIPT.json` in each `homebrew` package inside `/usr/local/Cellar`, e.g. this for OpenCV

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
```

It is standard JSON, so you can parse it like this without needing and additional tools:

```
python -mjson.tool /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
```

and you get this - which may help your cause... maybe.

```
    {
    "HEAD": "d60f75135ecf1a667539700ad7916cefbcc98480",
    "built_as_bottle": false,
    "compiler": "clang",
    "poured_from_bottle": false,
    "source": {
        "path": "/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/opencv.rb",
        "spec": "stable",
        "tap": "homebrew/homebrew-science"
    },
    "stdlib": "libcxx",
    "time": 1444317226,
    "unused_options": [
        "--32-bit",
        "--with-java",
        "--with-qt",
        "--with-tbb",
        "--without-tests",
        "--without-opencl",
        "--with-cuda",
        "--with-quicktime",
        "--with-opengl",
        "--with-ximea",
        "--without-numpy",
        "--without-python",
        "--c++11",
        "--without-eigen",
        "--with-gstreamer",
        "--with-jasper",
        "--with-libdc1394",
        "--without-openexr",
        "--with-openni",
        "--with-ffmpeg"
    ],
    "used_options": []
}
```

You can also get the output of the `brew info` command in JSON format, e.g.:

```
brew info imagemagick --json=v1 | jq "."
[
  {
    "name": "imagemagick",
    "full_name": "imagemagick",
    "desc": "Tools and libraries to manipulate images in many formats",
    "homepage": "http://www.imagemagick.org",
    "oldname": null,
    "versions": {
      "stable": "6.9.2-3",
      "bottle": true,
      "devel": null,
      "head": "HEAD"
    },
    "revision": 0,
    "installed": [
      {
        "version": "6.9.2-3",
        "used_options": [
          "--with-x11"
        ],
        "built_as_bottle": null,
        "poured_from_bottle": false
      }
    ],
    "linked_keg": "6.9.2-3",
    "keg_only": null,
    "dependencies": [
      "xz",
      "libtool",
      "pkg-config",
      "jpeg",
      "libpng",
      "libtiff",
      "freetype",
      "fontconfig",
      "little-cms",
      "little-cms2",
      "libwmf",
      "librsvg",
      "liblqr",
      "openexr",
      "ghostscript",
      "webp",
      "fftw",
      "pango"
    ],
    "conflicts_with": [],
    "caveats": null,
    "requirements": [
      {
        "name": "x11",
        "default_formula": null,
        "cask": "xquartz",
        "download": "https://xquartz.macosforge.org"
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "option": "--with-fftw",
        "description": "Compile with FFTW support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-hdri",
        "description": "Compile with HDRI support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-jp2",
        "description": "Compile with Jpeg2000 support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-openmp",
        "description": "Compile with OpenMP support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-perl",
        "description": "enable build/install of PerlMagick"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-quantum-depth-8",
        "description": "Compile with a quantum depth of 8 bit"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-quantum-depth-16",
        "description": "Compile with a quantum depth of 16 bit"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-quantum-depth-32",
        "description": "Compile with a quantum depth of 32 bit"
      },
      {
        "option": "--without-opencl",
        "description": "Disable OpenCL"
      },
      {
        "option": "--without-magick-plus-plus",
        "description": "disable build/install of Magick++"
      },
      {
        "option": "--without-jpeg",
        "description": "Build without jpeg support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--without-libpng",
        "description": "Build without libpng support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--without-libtiff",
        "description": "Build without libtiff support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--without-freetype",
        "description": "Build without freetype support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-x11",
        "description": "Build with x11 support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-fontconfig",
        "description": "Build with fontconfig support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-little-cms",
        "description": "Build with little-cms support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-little-cms2",
        "description": "Build with little-cms2 support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-libwmf",
        "description": "Build with libwmf support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-librsvg",
        "description": "Build with librsvg support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-liblqr",
        "description": "Build with liblqr support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-openexr",
        "description": "Build with openexr support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-ghostscript",
        "description": "Build with ghostscript support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-webp",
        "description": "Build with webp support"
      },
      {
        "option": "--with-pango",
        "description": "Build with pango support"
      }
    ],
    "bottle": {
      "stable": {
        "revision": 0,
        "cellar": "/usr/local/Cellar",
        "prefix": "/usr/local",
        "root_url": "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles",
        "files": {
          "el_capitan": {
            "url": "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/imagemagick-6.9.2-3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz",
            "sha256": "cd5edb53eae0271771df4a77a401a50e973b200ae875a04ef6a3f4d467ca2ef4"
          },
          "yosemite": {
            "url": "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/imagemagick-6.9.2-3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz",
            "sha256": "fbe139e4d7b540ce03fcde6a7735d9e79ed8652827cd7c877e551abcf804a494"
          },
          "mavericks": {
            "url": "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/imagemagick-6.9.2-3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz",
            "sha256": "99f2f95739d3ee11535fea62440f1608ce0ee1ef22bda2f878353360ab45e9cc"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Original Answer**

So you want the bottled packages which are not built from source.

```
# List all installed packages
for p in $(brew list); do
   # Get info about this particular one...
   # ... if bottled and not from source, print first line
   brew info $p | awk '/bottled/{p=$0} /Built from source/{p=""} END{if(length(p))print p}'
done
```

If you don't have too many packages installed, you may get away with this:

```
brew info $(brew list) | awk ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed what I was looking for in the `man brew` page but no luck for now

Comment: Unfortunately that script won't work because the string "bottled" is there anyway if a bottle is available for the package, but you can still compile from source. For example I've just built `yasm` from source and `brew info yasm` gives me:

`yasm: stable 1.3.0 (bottled), HEAD`
[...]
`/usr/local/Cellar/yasm/1.3.0 (44 files, 3.3M) *`
`Built from source`

Comment: Can you click `edit` underneath your question and put the additional information from the comment above into your question please - it is easier to read with the formatting there. Thanks

Comment: I don't have any such beasts on my system, but I think the above should be very close

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks, still no go: I've put an excerpt of the output of `brew info $(brew list)` in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mindrones/c992a2557fbf792eb3b9). Sometimes you have more than a version of a package and some package can have multiple versions both as a bottle or built from source so it's a bit tricky. Also the OS release name is still missing: it's probably better to file this as a homebrew issue :)

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't help - I don't have anything that complicated in my setup :-)