# List maintainers of brew formula

Tags: homebrew

Am writing a tool to automatically tip creators of packages.

With npm I am able to run `npm show 'package'` and list contributors and maintainers from the package.json file.
Is there an equivalent for brew packages?

Comment: I haven't looked at how **homebrew** works lately, but there may be something in the 2 locations mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31878329/2836621